# There are no redirect URIs registered with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We went live with DocuSign integration a while back. In the development, we're able to authenticate the DocuSign credentials of the user and then they're able to send documents for eSign.

After going live, our customers trying to authenticate their DocuSign credentials on our app are getting URI not present error.

Any idea where we're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the key again in the production environment.
These URIs are not copied over for you even after you went live.